# Update/Delete in type safe way - via usage of something like CriteriaQuery?

Tags: jpa, orm, eclipselink

Is there a possibility to make update/delete type safe operations of entities like querying with CriteriaQuery ?

My concrete situation for here is since I want to avoid Native query when I want to delete some set of entities with EclipseLink after a period of time. I am making where close with Date comparison and using Native SQL. Do you think that would be the best use case usage for my situation ? Personally I think that the ORM provider should make the SQL and to avoide native SQLs.

Thanks in advance for recommendations, 
Simeon

Answer (score 1):

Criteria API does not yet support bulk operations, but you can use regular JPQL update and delete queries. The provider will transalte them into SQL. In most cases there is no need to write native SQL yourself.

As example - raise an employees salary and then fire him:

```
UPDATE Employee e
SET e.salary = 99999
WHERE e.salary = 88888


DELETE FROM Employee e
WHERE e.salary = 99999
```

Comment: Thanks, but since there is no way to use Date comparison with JPQL in bulk operations, like in you example, I used Native and that's why I would like to avoid it. If there is a possibility of course

Comment: @SimeonAngelov - what do you mean by "there is no way"? you can operate with Date obejcts or with date literals like with other types in JPQL, bulk or not. Do you have a particular case that does not work?

Comment: As I read in resource flow in Internet there is no Date aritmentic with JPQL, am i right ? My particular situation is I want to remove entities with expired time with Query.executeUpdate() function, not using native query or saying with source code : 

    1. String query = "DELETE FROM A WHERE lastUsedTime <= ?"
    2. Query executeQuery = EM.createNativeQuery(query);
    3. executeQuery.executeUpdate();

And here, on 2-nd line, I would like to use for example createQuery() using JPQL or something other, but not using native query

Comment: For date operations in EclipseLink see, http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_extract.htm#extract or http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/j_sql.htm#sql